# AVAudioPlayer CPU consuming 95%?

Tags: macos, cocoa, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

i have almost finish my care project that play mp3 file by AVAudioPlayer. 
I started developing my app on MacPro Quad Core and all go great, but in my MacBook pro with this specifics: - MacBookPro5,5 - Intel Core 2 Duo - 2,26 GHz the App, when click Play, CPU usage go to 95% . 
This is an odd behavior! For clarification when i run the app the CPU consuming is 0%, when  i load trax in Tableview, after some peak, still remain in 0%. The overkill consuming come up as i click on play button: 95%. ...My static Analyzer sign "No Issue"

The question is: is normal that AVAudioPlayer consuming so much CPU for playing mp3 files?

where i can look for figure out the problem?[image]

Any help is largely appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did found the cause!

```
- (void)valueFromClickInView {
  //assuming theValue exist
  [self.currentTimeSlider setDoubleValue:theValue]; // 90% CPU usage

  }

- (void)valueFromClickInView {
  //assuming theValue exist
  [self.currentTimeSlider setIntegerValue:theValue]; // 25% CPU usage

  }
```

So the cause of the abnormal CPU consumption was caused by the value of the `NSSlider`.

Hope help thank you!